# Testing existence of connected component with react-redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, jestjs, enzyme

I'm trying to test a component that wraps a connected component.
So I have (simplified):

```
const InnerComponent = () => {
  return (
    <p>Hi!</p>
  )
}

const InnerComponentWrapper = connect()(InnerComponent)

const OuterComponent = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <InnerComponentWrapper>
    </div>
  )
}
```

(Obviously there's more to these components, including state related stuff)

Now I'm trying to simply test that InnerComponent (or InnerComponentWrapper) is in OuterComponent. I'm using jest+enzyme. When I render OuterComponent (shallow or mount) all I can find in OuterComponent is an element with the tag of 'Connect' which doesn't have anything on it I can find that can tell me what element it's wrapping.

What I tried:

```
const enzymeWrapper = shallow(<OuterComponent />)
expect(enzymeWrapper.find('Connect').length).toBe(1) // pass
expect(enzymeWrapper.find('Connect(InnerComponentWrapper)').length).toBe(1) // fail
expect(enzymeWrapper.find('InnerComponentWrapper').length).toBe(1) // fail
expect(enzymeWrapper.find('InnerComponent').length).toBe(1) // fail
```

Thanks!

Comment: Would `.dive()` help in your case? https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/dive.md

Answer (score 3):

For me, this works (your 2nd attempt, marked as not working… perhaps you got some detail wrong, or things got fixed in a newer version?).

```
const enzymeWrapper = shallow(<OuterComponent />)
expect(enzymeWrapper.find('Connect(InnerComponentWrapper)')
```

Also, the [Enzyme bug tracker](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/589) points to this solution.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the issue. One of the maintainers there suggests to never pass a string to `.find` though...

Comment: it also works for me, I am using enzyme 3.9.0 with enzyme-adapter-react-16 and react 16.8.6

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, there could definitely be a better one, but this hacky one will do for now:

```
const enzymeWrapper = shallow(<OuterComponent />)
expect(enzymeWrapper.find('Connect').node.type.WrappedComponent({})).toEqual(InnerComponent({}))
```

Comment: Yeah, sorry I don't think it's applicable.